# What's portable way to say ord(some_buffer[n])?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

```
> python2 -c "print(ord(b'a'[0]))" 
97
> python3 -c "print(ord(b'a'[0]))"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

How can I write this code in a way that would work both for Python 2 and Python 3?

Comment: I think the difference is not in `ord`, but in what `b'...'[0]` returns in both versions.

Comment: Yes, that's what the question is about, but I'd like to treat this structure as a whole - I don't mind replacing `ord` with another function as long as I get an ASCII integer for a character on a given index.

Comment: If you are willing to replace `ord` by some other function, just `try` to use ord and else return the int directly, or check the type, whether it's an int or str.

Comment: That's doesn't sound like the most clean solution. Are there any others?

Comment: The problem is the way indexing is implemented for byte strings in Python 3. Convert both to unicode and it'll work the same in both Python 2 and Python 3. `ord` will even give you results for things outside ASCII range, though you may want to control for that elsewhere.

Comment: I cannot, it contains binary data.

Comment: Also, I don't think it's going to give me results outside ASCII range if I just want ord() for one byte, will it?

Comment: I'm suggesting the Python-version-agnostic answer to the question in your title is `ord(unicode(some_buffer[n]))`. If whatever is in your buffer at that position is meaningless as unicode or can't be converted, then I would suggest the overall operation is just as meaningless. It's hard to give a better comment without knowing more.